# How can we use grpc channelz in Java

Tags: java, debugging, grpc, grpc-java

In the introduction to [grpc channelz article](https://grpc.io/blog/a-short-introduction-to-channelz/), it seems that there is support for channelz for both Golang and Java but the article only contains information related to Golang. After browsing through the web for java, I found [this](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/services/ChannelzService.html) ChannelzService implementation which seems to be deprecated now. Does anyone know how we can use channelz in java to figure out issues related to channels, sockets and servers.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some sample of gRPC in Java, maybe it could help you to use; You can refrence [github.com/helloworlde/grpc-java-sample](https://github.com/helloworlde/grpc-java-sample/tree/main/channelz) for more detail. Feel free for translate chinese

Comment: Thank you @HelloWood, I've tried all three of the tools you suggest in your git repo, but the grpcurl was the only one that worked for me (at least I got something...)

Answer (score 0):

The class you found has been relocated to `io.grpc.protobuf.services.ChannelzService`.

You linked to `io.grpc.services.ChannelzService`. If you look just under the horizontal line it says, "Use [ChannelzService](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/protobuf/services/ChannelzService.html) instead."

Comment: Thanks Eric. Can you please give some advice on how to use this as well ? 
Any sample code snippets would work.

Comment: Does this help you https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/tools/run_tests/xds_k8s_test_driver/framework/rpc/grpc_channelz.py ? This and other code calling this code could give you an idea of how to use channelz for debugging